# Programmatically download and insert README.md with photos into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, markdown

I have a [personal website](http://jabaridash.com) written in AngularJS and NodeJS, and in the [tech projects](http://jabaridash.com/#!/tech) section I would like to embed README.md from a project on GitHub my account (the same way github.com) does it. I don't think `iframe<>` works for md files. So I have tried converting to HTML and PDF.

The second part of the README.md I want looks like this:

[image]

In particular, I would like to import the README.md files into my HTML. I have found two ways to do it:

### Download the file, and convert to HTML.

```
var md_to_html = function(src, dest) {

  // Get the markdown
  var md = fs.readFileSync(src, "utf8");

  var converter = new Remarkable();

  var html = converter.render(md);

  fs.writeFile(dest, html, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log(dest + " was saved!");
  });
}
```

### Or Download the file, and convert to PDF.

```
var md_to_pdf = function(src, dest) {

  fs.createReadStream(src)
    .pipe(markdownpdf())
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest));
}
```

Both work, however the photo disappears. That is because the dependencies let's say `doc/img/photo.jpg` does not get downloaded with the README. I have also written scripts to download the dependencies. But neither insert the photo into the README.pdf or README.html.

Has anyone done something like this? Embedded markdown in HTML with photos, or converted them to PDF or HTML with photos? If I could just import it kind of like a PDF with `iframe<>` that would be ideal, but if not, I will program it myself. But how?

Comment: The URLs in the converted Markdown are likely relative to the location of the README. However, those relative URLs would no longer be valid on a separate website. When converting your Markdown to HTML, i'll need to adjust the URLs appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I figure the relative addresses don't work. Is there a way around this? I actually have downloaded the files into the proper location such that the relative addresses correct (for the Markdown file) before converting to PDF, but it still does not work.

Comment: We're going to need more info to help. At the least, your file structure and a sample of the rendered HTML.